# BERT outputs explained

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

The keys of the BERT encoder's output are `default`, `encoder_outputs`, `pooled_output` and `sequence_output`

As far as I can know, `encoder_outputs` are the output of each encoder, `pooled_output` is the output of the global context and `sequence_output` is the output context of each token (correct me if I'm wrong please). But what is `default`? Can you give me a more detailed explanation of each one?

[This is the link to the encoder](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what implementation of BERT you mean (perhaps add a link to documentation that says that)? Huggingface Transformers or something else? If yes, what class?

Comment: @Jindřich sure thing, I've added the link (tensorflow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tensorflow [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert) provide a very good explanation to the outputs you are asking about:

> The BERT models return a map with 3 important keys: pooled_output, sequence_output, encoder_outputs:
>
> pooled_output represents each input sequence as a whole. The shape is
> [batch_size, H]. You can think of this as an embedding for the entire
> movie review.
>
> sequence_output represents each input token in the context. The shape
> is [batch_size, seq_length, H]. You can think of this as a contextual
> embedding for every token in the movie review.
>
> encoder_outputs are the
> intermediate activations of the L Transformer blocks.
> outputs["encoder_outputs"][i] is a Tensor of shape [batch_size,
> seq_length, 1024] with the outputs of the i-th Transformer block, for
> 0 <= i < L. The last value of the list is equal to sequence_output

[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/86510) is another interesting discussion on the difference between the `pooled_output` and `sequence_output`, if you are interested.

The `default` output is equal to the `pooled_output`, which you can confirm here:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

tfhub_handle_preprocess = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3'
tfhub_handle_encoder = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8/1'

def build_classifier_model(name):
    text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='features')    
    bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, name='preprocessing')
    encoder_inputs = bert_preprocess_model(text_input)
    encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder) 
    outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
    net = outputs[name]
    return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)

sentence = tf.constant([
"Improve the physical fitness of your goldfish by getting him a bicycle"
])

classifier_model = build_classifier_model(name='default')
default_output = classifier_model(sentence)

classifier_model = build_classifier_model(name='pooled_output')
pooled_output = classifier_model(sentence)

print(default_output == pooled_output)
```